# How can I override a system call table entry with my own function?

Tags: c, security, linux-kernel, x86, system-calls

I want to update the system call table to use my custom open function. I wrote the following code:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kallsyms.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
char *sym_name = "sys_call_table";

typedef asmlinkage long (*sys_call_ptr_t)(const struct pt_regs *);
static sys_call_ptr_t *sys_call_table;
typedef asmlinkage long (*custom_open) (const char __user *filename, int flags, umode_t mode);

custom_open old_open;

static asmlinkage long my_open(const char __user *filename, int flags, umode_t mode)
{
    pr_info("%s\n",__func__);
        return old_open(filename, flags, mode);
}

static int __init hello_init(void)
{
    sys_call_table = (sys_call_ptr_t *)kallsyms_lookup_name(sym_name);
    old_open = (custom_open)sys_call_table[__NR_open];
    sys_call_table[__NR_open] = (sys_call_ptr_t)my_open;

    return 0;
}

static void __exit hello_exit(void)
{
    sys_call_table[__NR_open] = (sys_call_ptr_t)old_open;    
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

When I load the module, I get the following error:

```
[69736.192438] BUG: unable to handle page fault for address: ffffffff98e001d0
[69736.192441] #PF: supervisor write access in kernel mode
[69736.192442] #PF: error_code(0x0003) - permissions violation
[69736.192443] PGD 10460e067 P4D 10460e067 PUD 10460f063 PMD 80000001040000e1 
[69736.192461] Oops: 0003 [#1] SMP PTI
[69736.192463] CPU: 0 PID: 45249 Comm: insmod Tainted: G           OE     5.2.8 #6
```

Can I update the system call table? How can I resolve such an error?

Comment: Are you on x86?

Comment: X86_64 processor

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're almost there. In Intel x86 CPUs, the [Control Register `CR0`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_register) has a special bit (called Write Protect bit), to control whether the CPU can write to read-only pages while running in privilege level 0 (kernel code does run at privilege level 0).

Since the syscall table is inside a page that is read-only, and by default the "Write Protect" bit is set, you are prevented from writing to it. So if you attempt to do:

```
sys_call_table[__NR_open] = (sys_call_ptr_t)my_open;
```

you'll crash everything.

In order to hijack the syscall correctly you will need to disable write protection by setting the "Write Protect" bit of the `CR0` register to `0` before overwriting the table entry, and re-enable it after you're done. The two macros `read_cr0()` and `write_cr0()` are there exactly for manipulating said register.

Here's the correct code:

```
// Temporarily disable write protection
write_cr0(read_cr0() & (~0x10000));

// Overwrite the syscall table entry
sys_call_table[__NR_open] = /* whatever */;

// Re-enable write protection
write_cr0(read_cr0() | 0x10000);
```

The mask `0x10000` is used above since the "Write Protect" bit is the 17th least significant bit of the register.

Note that the above steps need to be done both in the `init` and `exit` functions of your module.

Comment: Bit 0 of CR0 is the PE bit (protected mode). Bit 0x10000 is the Write Protect (WP) bit. Linux will enable the WP bit so even the kernel (running at ring 0) will fault when writing to a read-only page. Temporarily turning it off prevents that.

Comment: Updating Bit 0x10000 before updating the system call table works. But my custom function is not being called now... Am i missing any other thing

Comment: @md.jamal not sure about that, those casts that you do really seem unneeded to me. Add some more `printk` and see what happens.

Comment: There is already one printk present. Is there any benefit of adding multiple

Comment: @md.jamal why not? Unless you want to recompile your kernel with debugging support, that's the only tool you have. Also, consider using `pr_alert()` instead of `pr_info()`, there's the possibility that you don't see the print because the log level of your system is set too low. See [here](https://elinux.org/Debugging_by_printing) for more info.

Comment: Did not work. I will post that as a separate question, as it is a different problem